# check value of drop-down list at load and on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop-down list that I need to capture the value of when the page is loaded and whenever it is changed. If the report field is not selected, do not display state-list or year-list, if the report field is selected (whether on load or when the user selects it from the drop-down), display the appropriate div.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {
 checkReport();
});

</script>

<select name="report" id="report">
<option></option>
<option value="state">State</option>
<option value="year">Year</option>
</select>

<div id="state-list">NY, CA, TX</div>

<div id="year-list">2012, 2013, 2014</div>

function checkReport() {

  $('#report').live('change', function() {
    $('#year-list, #state-list).hide();
    var report = $('#report').val();

    if (report) {
      $('#' + type_of_report + '-list').show();
    } else {
      $('#year-list, #state-list).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You've described what you need, but what's the problem? What is your code not doing?

Comment: Any reason why you went with one solution over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
checkReport();
 $('#report').live('change', checkReport);
});

function checkReport() {
    var report = $('#report').val();
    $('#year-list, #state-list').hide();
    if (report) {
      $('#' + report + '-list').show();
    }
}
```

Thats what you need i guess

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
<select name="report" id="report">
    <option value="">Select a type of report</option>
    <option value="state">State</option>
    <option value="year">Year</option>
</select>

<div id="state-list">NY, CA, TX</div>

<div id="year-list">2012, 2013, 2014</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(function(){

    checkReport($('#report')[0]);

    $('#report').on('change', function() {
        checkReport(this);
    });

    function checkReport(r) {            
        $('#year-list,#state-list').hide().filter(function(){
            return r.value.length > 0 &&   
             $(this).is('#' + r.value + '-list')
        }).show();            
    }
});

</script>
```

**Proof:** http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/qvq3z/

**Notes:**

1. I replaced the blank option with instructions.
2. You don't need `$('#report').on('change',` because the `select` is part of the DOM originally. No need to capture it live. You can just do:  `$('#report').change(`. I only added it to keep the `live` functionality displayed in your question.